# Delete model by primary key in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to delete a model (not sure that's what it's called in SQLAlchemy, I'm coming from Django) without actually querying and loading the full object in the session? Ie. something like this:

```
a = MyModel()
a.uid = 2             # this is the primary key
sess.delete(a)
```

This however throws an error: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Instance '<MyModel at 0x7f69d112e210>' is not persisted`

And I don't want to `instance = session.query(MyModel).filter_by(uid=1).first()` and then `delete` that, because I already have the IDs, I don't want to make useless queries.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you don't want to use raw SQL, the ORM queries can also [delete objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#deleting-based-on-filter-criterion):

```
session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.uid == 2).delete()
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Then, why you can't use `session.execute` like [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html?highlight=session.ex#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute)

```
session.execute(
        "DELETE FROM mymodal WHERE uid=:param",
        {"param":2}
    )
session.flush()
```

Comment: Do I also need to call `session.commit()` after this? Currently it only works if I do. Just want to make sure I'm doing it right. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need to call `session.flush()`. Because `session.execute()` method does not invoke autoflush.